# How can I get specific value from $http.get in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a simple question. When I use $http.get in angular controller, how can I use a specific value from the results? Let's say that I am getting username and password and I want to compare each one individually.

```
app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $http.get("../Views/userAuthentecation.aspx")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.members = response.data;            
        });
    }
});
```

From the above controller, I am using the `userAuthentecation.aspx` to read from database in the behind code and just display the results as json format. So, the `$scope.members` is actually a json format data contains username and password.

Comment: You mean like response.data.password?

Comment: I am not really sure because I am new to Angular. But in general because I will need to check specific values frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Well generally we assign an entire response to a single object like you did

```
$scope.members = response.data;
```

but lets say if you have 3 objects in `response.data` and you want them all to be in the different objects than you can simply assign them to different objects like below

```
$scope.id = response.data.id; 

$scope.username = response.data.username;

$scope.members = response.data.password;
```

once the data is assigned to `$scope.objects` than you can do with it whatever you like but Since you have authentication code in your controller i suppose you are trying to make an authentication system. well in that case once the login form is filled its been send to a function in controller for authentication for example

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
```

once the controller gets the request you can either process it in the same function or you can send it to authentication service which is usually a factory to perform a specific task in this case it will check the user crediantials.

```
$scope.login = function () {
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                $scope.error = response.message;
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

the above function is calling another factory for authenticating the user credentials, the factory `AuthenticationService` will be called which will pass the parameters to `Login()` function. function within the factory can be called like this

```
AuthenticationService.login()
```

once the credentials are checked and verfied and response code is 200 which means `ok` then entered creditals will be passed to

```
AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
```

which will generated encrypted cookie

hope this will give a little understand about authentication and comparing the response data, the entire workig authentication example can be found [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/H4SVl6/preview)

Comment: you are welcome :) please like my post by clicking up arrow, if you find my answer useful.

Comment: I am still new to stackoverflow. So, I am not able to click on the up arrow, but I will keep it in mind. However, in the part that you provided, how can I compare the username and password from textboxes to username and password from database? `AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response)`

Comment: Let me tell you that in the anwer box, please look for update

Comment: Thanks, I will be waiting for your feedback

Comment: AuthenticationService.Login is a siimple factory which is making a post request by sending the data $scope.username and $scope.password to the backend API, weather its REST API or general backend if the username password matches the one from DB it return true with creating a session.

Comment: if you need any other help please ask me anytime, sorry for the late reply my system wasn't working.